# Why I am getting two different response in browsser console and network tab

Tags: javascript, json, api, response

I am making an API call from my script.js file. when I send a message to chatbot It gives me two different responses in Inspect->console and Inspect->network tab.

> Network tab

[image: THis is network tab]

> Console tab

[image: This is console tab]

> script.js

```
fetch(`${url}/conversations/default/respond`, {
        mode: 'no-cors',
        method: 'POST',
        // dataType:'jsonp',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log("RESPONSE",response);
            if (response) {
                for (let response of response) {
                console.log(response.text);
                    createResponder(response.text);
            }
            } else {
                createResponder("Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding you, try asking me in an other way")
            }
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            //console.log("DIFF",err);
            document.getElementById('typing').style.display = "none";
            createResponder("I'm having some technical issues. Try again later :)");
        });
```

Comment: That is because in the network tab you're looking at the response's body and in the console, you're logging the entire `Response` object returned by `fetch` which includes the headers and some other metadata.

Comment: You should read the [DOCUMENTATION](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to learn how to use `fetch`

Answer (score 1):

The network tab contains all data for the request life, its start, its response status, headers, data etc etc...

On this part :

```
.then(function (response) {
            console.log("RESPONSE",response);
            if (response) {
                for (let response of response) {
                console.log(response.text);
                    createResponder(response.text);
            }
            } else {
                createResponder("Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding you, try asking me in an other way")
            }
        })
```

you are console logging the xhr object itself, this is why your console contains "request" data and not your json data, that i guess you are expecting.

Keep on reading [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and pay attention to "Response objects" section

Comment: Actually, I want that "text" from the network tab. and I am unable to find that in response. I tried `response.text` `response.body` but not getting.

Comment: @sheel Both `response.text` and `response.body` are `Promises`, you'll have to use something like `response.text().then(txt => console.log(txt))` but it looks like you need `response.json()` not `response.text()`, just read the documentation.